# Find a specific registration key with a value of 'New Signature'

Tags: powershell, registry

I'm trying to find a specific registration key with the name 'New Signature'

The solution I'm using now is:

$regTest = Get-ChildItem 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676'

The output is-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzdWH.png)

I can see the key is under 00000005

Then I do :

$regTest | Get-ItemProperty -Name 'New Signature' | select PSChildName

-OutVariable gg

Then i'll get a lot of errors.

Get-ItemProperty : Property New Signature does not exist at path HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\9
375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\00000003.

Get-ItemProperty : Property New Signature does not exist at path HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\9
375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\00000006.
At line:1 char:12
+ $regTest | Get-ItemProperty -Name 'New Signature' | select PSChildNam ...

But I'll also get the right one

### PSChildName

00000005

So now $gg output is:

### PSChildName

00000005

Does anyone know how to find the key without getting all the errors?

When I do:

Get-Item 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676'

The output is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4c2w.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to retrieve?

```
$regTest = (Get-Item 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676'|
 Get-ItemProperty).'New Signature'
```

Comment: If I do:

$regTest = (Get-Item 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676'|
 Get-ItemProperty).'New Signature'

$regTest has no output

Comment: what do you mean by 'no output'? is it `$null`?

Comment: $regTest is empty. There is nothing in the variable

Comment: what does this command return - 
`Get-Item 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676'`

Comment: I have edit my question so you can see the output from :

Get-Item 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676'

Comment: This is proper output, but you don't have 'New Signature' key.

Comment: I found a solution.
If I use:

$Test = Get-ChildItem -Path 'hkcu:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676' -Recurse | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_ -match 'New Signature'} | select PSChildName 


Then $Test output is


PSChildName
00000005 And I'm not getting any errors

Comment: Thanks for your help Max has really appreciate it